# Custom payment gateway woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i use this `plugin https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-payment-gateways-woocommerce/`
I'm using lite version. Configured woocommerce settings and checkout. How can i add payment method for this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You will open the woo commerce settings option in admin and there is a tab for "Payments" and select "Custom Payment " Tab and add your details in custom payment tab